# ionic 3 responsive popover size

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic3

i am using ionic 3 and have a popover which has a fixed height using

```
editOpty(rw){
     let popover = this.editOptyPopup.create(EditOptyPopoverComponent, rw, { cssClass: 'edit-opty-popover'});
    popover.present({

    });
  }
```

the css is like:

```
.edit-opty-popover .popover-content{
        width: 1400px;
 }
```

the downside are obvious of the fixed width. All I need is the popup width to be few pixels less than the screen (whicherver i am using) width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `%` here.

```
.edit-opty-popover .popover-content{
        max-width: 90%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
width:calc(100vw - 5px)
```

or

```
width:calc(100% - 5px)
```

depending on your need.